# Why is it okay to omit the limits on some definite integrals?

Tags: probability, soft-question, notation, expectation, independence

To illustrate, here is a textbook example for deriving the formula for the expectation of two independent random variables:

If a random variable $x_1$ has probability density $\rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1$ and another random variable $x_2$ has probability density $\rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2$. Then the joint probability density is the product of the two separate probability densities:

$$\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2=\rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1\rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2$$

So the expectation is
$$E(X)= \langle x_1+ x_2\rangle=\iint(x_1+x_2)\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2$$
$$=\int x_1\rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1\int \rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2+\int \rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1\int x_2 \rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2$$
$$=\langle x_1\rangle+\langle x_2\rangle=E_1+E_2$$

Now, since by definition $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_1\rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1=E_1$$
and $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_2\rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2=E_2$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2=1$$

So it must be the case that
$$\underbrace{\int x_1\rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1}_{=E_1}\underbrace{\int \rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2}_{=1}+\underbrace{\int \rho_1(x_1)\mathrm{d}x_1}_{=1} \underbrace{\int x_2 \rho_2(x_2)\mathrm{d}x_2}_{=E_2}$$

So why have the limits been omitted?

---

### In response to the comments below:

Is the word **expectation** enough context to imply $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$?

Comment: this is ok when the limits of integration are always the same and defined somewhere. in your case it is clear that it is the support of your prob. distributions

Comment: It's just an omission for brevity to show why and how : $\mathsf E(X_1+X_2) = \mathsf E(X_1)+\mathsf E(X_2)$.

Comment: If it's clear from context what interval you're integrating over, then people might omit the limits of integration just to save writing.

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your reply, so when the word expectation is used is that 'context enough' to mean integrate over the entire real line?

Comment: @BLAZE : Not in all cases.  Sometimes the integral might only be over $[0,1]$ or $[0\infty)$ and that might also be clear from the context.

Comment: @BLAZE It's quite often over all the reals... but not always. Take it to mean "the limits that you know are expected for the situation but are too lazy to write out again and again."

Comment: In more than a few quantum mech. notes, I've seen $\int dx\phi\phi^*$ imply over the reals in one line and in the next line imply from $[0,\infty)$ just because you *know* the particular function vanishes for $x<0$. When there's an abrupt change, though, it's usually noted somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For a single absolutely continuous random variable, yes.

---

Consider the first expectation:

$$E(X)= \langle x_1+ x_2\rangle=\iint(x_1+x_2)\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2$$

This is supposed to be:

$$E(X)= \langle x_1+ x_2\rangle=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}(x_1+x_2)\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2$$

or

$$E(X)= \langle x_1+ x_2\rangle=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}(x_1+x_2)\rho(x_1,x_2)\mathrm{d}x_1\mathrm{d}x_2$$

---

Going back to the one variable case:

$$E[X] = \int_{\mathbb R} xf_X(x)dx$$

In the case where the expectation is not well-defined because of a certain subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, then

$$E[X] = \int_{\mathbb R} xf_X(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb R \setminus A} xf_X(x)dx,$$

provided the integral is well-defined.

If $$\int_{B} xf_X(x)dx = 0$$ for $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, then $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} xf_X(x)dx = \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus B} xf_X(x)dx$$

---

For a single continuous random variable, the pdf may not exist.

---

For a single discrete random variable.

$$E[X] = \sum_{x \in Range(X)} xf_X(x)dx$$

If $Range(X) =\mathbb{R}$, $X$ is not discrete.